# How to check in JS if user selected a file in file input on Android 2.3.7

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I have a file field on a webpage in HTML like this:

```
<input name='a' id='a' type='file' />
```

On latest FF, Chrome and IE 11, also on Android 4.42 Chrome i can chec if person choose a file by doing:

```
document.getElementsByName('a')[0].value != ""
```

And it works properly.

But somehow on Android 2.3.7 native browser after i choose a file from a image gallery that was taken with a phone camera i see the name of the file in the file input selection field, but the script above returns false since value is empty.

So, how to properly check if a user selected a file in input file field in Android 2.3.7 native browser?

I add jQuery in case it has some proven solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input name='a' id='a' type='file' onchange="onFileChange(this)"/>
<script>
    function onFileChange(file){
        if(file.value){
            alert('File is selected');
        }
        else{
            alert('File is not selected');
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've runned it and received "File is not selected"

Comment: Have you tried selecting file from gallery in **2.3.7** ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have tried it on 2.3.7 and selected file from gallery (the build one)

Comment: I have had faced similar issues in **2.3**. If you clear the browser data and reset the device then it works in some cases. It can be termed as **Device Issue**

Comment: Thanks mate. I think i just consider onfilechange as a hint file was in fact selected.

Comment: I got it running but it did not upload file to server. It seems 2.3.* and dont know how long after Android didnt support file upload at all in native browser https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2519

Comment: Just check what exact data is being transmitted over the network(Developers Tools -> network panel)